# How to fix "Trust boundary violation -Security Issue" in Coverity (Security Tool similar to veracode) in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, esapi, coverity, veracode

I'm getting the below security issue while scanning the file.

"Using the tainted data "value" in a context that is often assumed to be trustworthy. Because trusted data may not be validated or sanitized, this data could be mistakenly used in an insecure manner."

I tried to fix in 3 ways as below but no luck as security issue still shows in the same line after re-scanning the file.

```
1) String value = request.getParameter(key);   
    if(value.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z_]+"){  
       if (key.startsWith("BOOKMARK"))
           book.put(key, value);
       else     
          session.setAttribute(key, value);
       }

2) String value = request.getParameter(key);  
    ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("Value", value, "valuePattern", 100,  false);
    if (key.startsWith("BOOKMARK"))             
        book.put(key, value);       
    else            
        session.setAttribute(key, value);
                }

3)String value = request.getParameter(key);
    if (session.getAttribute(key) != null) { 
       if (key.startsWith("BOOKMARK"))  
           book.put(key, value);
       else   
           session.setAttribute(key, value);
    }
```

Below is Code Snippet and security issue shows in this line.

session.setAttribute(key, value);

```
private Bookmark cacheRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String key;
        Bookmark book = new Bookmark();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Enumeration enumVar = request.getParameterNames();
        System.out.println("after  enumVar creation");
        try {
            while (enumVar.hasMoreElements()) {
                key = (String) enumVar.nextElement();

                String value = request.getParameter(key);

                if (key.startsWith("BOOKMARK"))
                    book.put(key, value);
                else
                    session.setAttribute(key, value); //flaw
            }

        } catch (java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException value) {
        }
return book;
    }
```

I expected no tainted "value" which comes from an Http request in this line

```
session.setAttribute(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two paths to cover here:

1.)  Input Validation, which your call in #2 covers with ESAPI validation.  (Not sure which validator you're grabbing there!)

2.)  Handing off to another layer.  In this case you're setting it into the session,  which is going to stay on the server.  The discipline that you need to use to successfully navigate this issue (and others like it, such as SQL Injection or XSS) is to trace your data path and ask yourself every time you're about to process that data, "Is this being passed off to an interpreter?"

Every time the answer is "yes," you escape that input for that context.  In your case, where else am I using this session value in my code?  If you're then passing it to an SQL query, you use your ORM utilities or PreparedStatements if you're doing direct database access.  On the front end, if that value will ever be handed off back for user display, you need to escape for the proper contexts there too:  If you're doing a Single Page Web Application you'll want to encode for Javascript/JSON, or if it's ajax, XML/HTML, etc.

In short, any time your "trust boundary" is being crossed, you're being asked to evaluate whether or not your input value is being handed off to an interpreter.  If yes, encode, if no, ignore.  If it helps, diagram ALL the interpreters your application has, and make sure that you constantly have a strategy for every hand off.  With a little practice, this becomes second nature.